# Unexpected result while generating string with Aggregate() in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

[FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ftRxLq)

**Utility Function:**

```
  public static string GetProperties<T>(string alias="")
    {
       if (alias.Length>0)
       {
          return typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).Aggregate((x, y) => 
            alias + " = " + alias + "." + x + "," + Environment.NewLine + alias + " = " + alias + "." + y + ",");
       }
       else
       {
           return typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).Aggregate((x, y) => x + Environment.NewLine + y);
       }
    }
```

**Code**:

```
    public class ContainerInLog
    {

        public int ContainerInLogID { get; set; }
        public int ContainerInID { get; set; }
        public int CargoID { get; set; }      
        public int LoadStatus { get; set; }    

    }

    public static void Main()
    {
         string list = GetProperties<ContainerInLog>("y");
        Console.WriteLine(list);
    }
```

**Result:**

```
y = y.y = y.y = y.ContainerInLogID,
y = y.ContainerInID,,
y = y.CargoID,,
y = y.LoadStatus,
```

**Expected Result:**

```
ContainerInLogID = y.ContainerInLogID,
ContainerInID = y.ContainerInID,
CargoID = y.CargoID,
LoadStatus = y.LoadStatus,
```

Comment: That fiddle is not what you have posted here...

Comment: @DavidG apologies, please check now.

Comment: Don't use `Aggregate` with strings. You generate a lot of intermediate strings which are then thrown away, making it expensive. Use `string.Join` / a `StringBuilder` as appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are really stuck on returning the entire concatenated string instead of returning an enumerable of them, I wouldn't use `Aggregate` here, just use `string.Join`. Also, you can simplify the statement by crafting the string inside the `Select`. For example:

```
return string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    typeof(T)
        .GetProperties()
        .Select(x => $"{x.Name} = {alias}.{x.Name},"));
```

Bonus: If you change the separator to `$",{Environment.NewLine}"` you can remove the inline comma and you won't get the final comma on the end of your string ([example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dk6y3C)).

Comment: That is working just fine. But could you tell me what was causing the initial `y.y = y.y`

Comment: Well what changed? What is different? Are you using the latest version of C#?

Comment: nothing that I can think of. I am using vs2013, .net framework 4.5.1

Comment: That means you're not using a modern version of the C# compiler, which means the `$"...."` notation doesn't work. Replace those with `string.Format`.

Comment: that's strange, because it worked the first few times.

Comment: Then you weren't using `$"..."` string interpolation or you were using a newer version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

@DavidG has the nicer solution here, but whats going wrong with your aggregation is the following:

```
.Aggregate((x, y) => 
            alias + " = " + alias + "." + x + "," + Environment.NewLine + alias + " = " + alias + "." + y + ",");
```

The `Aggregate` selector function (your `(x,y)`) takes the following form:

```
Func<TAccumulate,TResult> resultSelector
```

That means in your case, `x` is the accumulated aggregate result already, eg `"ContainerInLogID = y.ContainerInLogID"`.

But to make the next aggregate, you transform `x` again: `alias + " = " + alias + "." + x`, making `"y = y.y = y.ContainerInLogID"`. And so on for each following property, each one adding another prefix of `"y = y."`.

Comment: Thanks, saves me having to write this out :)